# Transforming a XSLT: copying contents

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input for a XSL file:

```
<node>
    <xsl:value-of select="ROOT/LEVEL1/LEVEL2" />
</node>
```

My expected output is:

```
<node2>
    <xsl:value-of select="ROOT/LEVEL1/LEVEL2" />
</node2>
```

How to get this?

The best I could do:

```
<xsl:template match="node" >
    <node2>
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </node2>
</xsl:template>
```

Which produces:

```
<node2><node>
    <xsl:value-of select="ROOT/LEVEL1/LEVEL2"/>
</node></node2>
```

Comment: Can you show the XML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `<xsl:copy-of select="." />` will copy the existing node, but in your case you just want to copy the children. Instead try this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
```

Actually, it may be better to make use of the identity template, as this would allow you to make further transformations to the child elements of the **node** element rather than just copy as-is. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="node">
      <node2>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </node2>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! you've also helped me solve another problem I had: filtering the nodes to copy. 

    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[local-name() != 'shouldntGoThrough']"/>

Comment: It might actually be clearer to add a template to match "shouldntGoThrough" and just do nothing in the template. For example `<xsl:template match="shouldntGoThrough" />`. This should have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, except that there are some elements that need "shouldntGoThrough" so I couldn't block it out completely. In the meantime, I've found that I could've done what you said: add a template for "shouldntGoThrough" and act (output it or block it/do nothing) based on the parent.